# Windows: Avoid confirmation dialog when running excutables in network drives

Tags: windows, network-drive

How can I get rid of the confirmation dialog that appears when I try to run an executable which is located in a network drive?

Is there any configuration option somewhere to stop Windows from asking me the same thing every time?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/346042/windows-xp-cannot-execute-binary-file-on-network-share/422735#422735

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to go to your Internet Options window in Control Panel and add whatever server you are connecting to the "Local Intranet" group.

[image]

You may need to move the slider from `medium-low` to `low` or go in to the custom level settings and check the radial buttons for anything listed as "prompt" if it is still not working.